# Jenkins - Locating maven-wrapper.properties in wrong path

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Below is the snippet from scripted pipeline(Jenkins):

```
    sh 'echo ${WORKSPACE}'

    env.PATH="${WORKSPACE}/xyz-app:${env.PATH}"

    sh '${WORKSPACE}/xyz-app/mvnw clean install'
```

that gives below error:

```
+ /app/jenkins/workspace/CU_project/for_xyz/xyz-app/mvnw clean install
/app/jenkins/workspace/CU_project/for_xyz/xyz-app/mvnw: 236: /app/jenkins/workspace/CU_project/for_xyz/xyz-app/mvnw: cannot open /app/jenkins/workspace/CU_project/for_xyz/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties: No such file
/app/jenkins/workspace/CU_project/for_xyz/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar: No such file or directory
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
```

---

`echo ${WORKSPACE}` gives `/app/jenkins/workspace/CU_project/for_xyz`

---

As per the above error: `/app/jenkins/workspace/CU_project/for_xyz/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties` is wrong path for file `maven-wrapper.properties`.

Correct path is `/app/jenkins/workspace/CU_project/for_xyz/xyz_app/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties`

---

How to configure workspace for `mvnw` to pick arguments from correct path?

Comment: Use the Maven version installed in Jenkins via Global Tools configuration and don't use wrapper in Jenkins...apart from that in Pipelines you should use `withMaven(...)`

Comment: @khmarbaise As per the developer, he provided instructions to use `mvnw`

Comment: @khmarbaise Can I give explicit path to `maven-wrapper.properties` &  `maven-wrapper.jar` before invoking `mvnw`?

Comment: You jenkins is open to download from Maven Central?

Comment: @khmarbaise No, Jenkins is not open to download from maven central

Comment: @khmarbaise How to give explicit path for `maven-wrapper.properties` & `maven-wrapper.jar` as options to run `mvnw`?

Comment: so you won't get maven wrapper running inside Jenkins cause it will download the maven distribution by default from Maven Central...

Comment: @khmarbaise Am sorry.. `/app/jenkins/workspace/CU_project/for_xyz/xyz_app/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties` file has content `distributionUrl=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.5.4/apache-maven-3.5.4-bin.zip`. So, I think Jenkins is open to download from Maven central

Comment: Haven checked that the `maven-wrapper.jar` is correctly checked in into the project? It does not look like this?

Comment: @khmarbaise `ws('/app/..../xyz-app'){}` helped me run `mvnw` perfectly fine